# Grails .save(flush: true) does not save data instantly

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Situation :

I send a request using Grails resource and service named firstService;

First request's task is

1. save a book instance book1  `book1.save(flush: true);`
2. at the same time wait 60 sec or a property of book1 is updated by another request by second request

But when I save with `book1.save(flush: true);` it does not save instantly and thats why withing 60 sec the second request can not find that book1 instance;

Second request's task is only updating data of first request.

How can I solve the problem ?

Comment: Is your object persists in DB if yes, how much time it takes?

Comment: Book is a domain object and even it shows primary key id after  book1.save(flush: true), but I could not get the data in second request

Comment: Did you check if there any constraint is violated during save using: failOnError: true?

Comment: book1.save(flush: true) returns true, here is noticeable thing is - After the first request the book1 is saved properly. But I need to do that while running the first request.

Answer (score 7):

book1.save() do not returns `true`, returns itself (book1) or returns null when errors.

There are four ways of to tell if object can be saved

- `validate` method *before* save. It should to return true
- `hasErrors` property *before* save. It should to return false
- `save` method returns the instance if all is ok
- `save` method with `(failOnError: true)` argument raise an error when validation fails

If you're totally certain that the object was saved then check this:

- Are you saving the object in a test context? Tests cleans the database and you must to create the object in each or to use `setup` method to create it
- Are you saving the object in a service? Services are transactional, thus if an error raise after the save then all the transaction is rollback.

Note: Every Grails developer must to read the @pledbrook articles `GORM Gotchas`

- https://spring.io/blog/2010/06/23/gorm-gotchas-part-1/
- https://spring.io/blog/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/
- https://spring.io/blog/2010/07/28/gorm-gotchas-part-3/

Comment: Another, very long read, is the 11 part series that points out a lot of the major issues with Hibernate/GORM: http://rpeszek.blogspot.com/2014/08/i-dont-like-hibernate-and-grails-part-1.html

Comment: What if you catch the thrown error in the service. Will the transaction still rollback?

Comment: Yes, which is one of the reasons the ORM needs work, catching your own exceptions should not mean an error in the transaction as a whole.